# Recursion in MIPS

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips, fibonacci

I'm working on a recursion problem in MIPS. It's not quite the usual factorial recursion problem. Instead, f(n) = 3*f(n - 1) + 2(n-1). I've looked at MIPS examples of the normal factorial problems, and they more or less make sense, but I can't get this variant of it to work. In the code below, I am trying just to output f(n) = 3*f(n-1) for n = 1 and f(0) = 2, which should give me 6. Instead, I get 3. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much!

```
.align 2

.text 
.globl main 

main: 
    subu    $sp, $sp, 32        #stack frame of 32 bytes 
    sw      $ra, 20($sp)        #save return address 
    sw      $fp, 16($sp)        #save frame pointer  
    addiu   $fp, $sp, 28        #set up frame pointer 
    li      $a0, 0             #test with factorial 5 
    jal     func              #call factorial 

   move     $a0, $v0
   li       $v0, 1
   syscall                    #print integer 

   lw       $ra, 20($sp)        #restore return address 
   lw       $fp, 16($sp)        #restore frame pointer 
   addiu    $sp, $sp, 32        #pop stack frame 
   jr       $ra 

func: 
   subu     $sp, $sp, 32        #stack frame of 32 bytes 
   sw       $ra, 20($sp)        #save return address 
   sw       $fp, 16($sp)        #save frame pointer 
   addiu    $fp, $sp, 28        #set up frame pointer 
   sw       $a0, 0($fp)     #save argument n

   lw       $v0, 0($fp)    #load argument n 
   bgtz      $v0, recurse     #go to recursion branch if n > 0
   li       $v0, 2        #else return 2 
   jr       base             #jump to base case code to return 

recurse: 
   lw       $v1, 0($fp) #load argument n 
   subu     $v0, $v1, 1         #compute n - 1 
   move     $a0, $v0            #move value n - 1 to $a0 
   jal  func                #call func again 

lw      $v0, 0($fp)         #load argument n - 1 
li      $t2, 2              #load constant 2 
li      $t3, 3              #load constant 3 
mul     $v0, $v0, $t3       #compute 3(n - 1), $v0 holds f(n - 1)   

base:                           #v0 stores result 
lw      $ra, 20($sp)        #restore $ra 
lw      $fp, 16($sp)        #restore $fp 
addiu       $sp, $sp, 32        #pop stack 
jr      $ra             #return to caller
```

.data 
ans:        .asciiz "The answer is"
newline:    .asciiz "\n"

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Any reason in particular why you're overwriting the return value right after `f(n-1)` returns?